# Meteor publish - How to publish data and check using profile information

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

My question is really simple but unfortunately I didn't found anywhere.

I have a collection of maps for example and I'm using Meteor.user().profile.mapsId to check if 
that user is allowed to see that maps.

First approach:

server/server.js

```
Meteor.publish('map', function (mapOwner) {
  var user =  Meteor.user();
  var mapId = user.profile.mapId;
  return Map.find({mapOwner: mapId});
});
```

Didn't work because publish don't accept Meteor.user();

Second approach:

server/server.js

```
    Meteor.publish('map', function (mapOwner) {
          return Map.find({mapOwner: Meteor.call('mapsCall')});
        });
```

collections/maps.js

```
Map = new Meteor.SmartCollection('map');

Meteor.methods({
  mapsCall: function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  var startupId = user.profile.startupId;
  return startupId;
  }
});
```

When I call Map.find().fetch() don't have anything..

What is the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach looks correct, but you need to load the user another way because `Meteor.user()` isn't available in publish functions. Just do:

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
```